# Множественное наследие OOП

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть три класса: `A, B` и `C`. Как классу `C` унаследовать параметры и методы классов `A` и `B`?

```js
/**
 * @class A
 */
function A (name) {
 this.name = name;
}

A.prototype.methodA = function(){
 console.log("name:" + this.name)
};

/**
 * @class B
 */
function B (age) {
 this.age  =  age;
}

B.prototype.methodB = function(){
 console.log("age:" + this.age)
};

/**
 * @class C exstend A and B
 */

function C () {}
```

При условии, что `A` и `B` не связанны друг с другом.
при создании экземпляра `pointof`.

```js
pointof = new C ('alex', 35)
```

В консоль должно быть следующие:

```js
console.log(pointof.name)  //'alex'
console.log(pointof.age)   //35
pointof.methodA()          //"name:alex"
pointof.methodB()          //"age:35"

pointof instanceof A       //true
pointof instanceof B       //true
pointof instanceof C       //true
```

Comment: Это вы сами себе такое задание придумали или где?

Comment: на собеседовании спрашивали , вот и решил разобраться

Comment: А там прям точь в точь вот так спрашивали? и Сказали что точно есть путь так сделать?

Comment: не на бумаге нарисовали классы A, B и C и спросили как унаследовать

Comment: Тогда  почему вы решили, что B не надо наследовать от A, а C от B?))

Comment: я так и сказал но там промолчали ) но я нашел как унаследовать параметры а вот методы пока не понял как наследовать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В версиях языка раньше ES 2015 (он же ES6, "Harmony") желаемого вами поведения добиться невозможно: если конструкторы A и B никак не связаны друг с другом, то одна из проверок `x instanceof A` или `x instanceof B` обязана вернуть false.

Тем не менее, начиная с Harmony появилась возможность переопределять оператор instanceof при помощи [`Symbol.hasInstance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance).

Поэтому множественное наследование можно реализовать следующим образом.

Для начала, функция-конструктор должна вызывать оба базовых конструктора:

```
function C(name, age) {
    A.call(this, name);
    B.call(this, age);
}
```

Далее, от одного из классов следует отнаследоваться обычным способом:

```
C.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;
```

От второго класса нужно отнаследоваться вручную:

```
Object.defineProperties(C.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(B.prototype));
```

Однако, эта строчка работает только когда B ни от кого сам не унаследован. Иначе надо честно идти по цепочке прототипов:

```
var chain = [];
for (let base = B.prototype; base && !base.isPrototypeOf(C.prototype); base = Object.getPrototypeOf(base)) 
    chain.push(base);
chain.reverse(); // Обход должен идти от предка к потомку, а мы прошли наоборот
for (const base of chain)
    Object.defineProperties(C.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(base));
```

Теперь в `C.prototype` есть все свойства из обоих прототипов предков, осталось сделать так чтобы проверка `pointof instanceof B` работала:

```
Object.defineProperty(B, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: function (obj) { 
        return B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj) || C.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
});
```

Вот весь код вместе:

```js
/**
 * @class A
 */
function A (name) {
 this.name = name;
}

A.prototype.methodA = function(){
 console.log("name:" + this.name)
};

/**
 * @class B
 */
function B (age) {
 this.age  =  age;
}

B.prototype.methodB = function(){
 console.log("age:" + this.age)
};

/**
 * @class C exstend A and B
 */

function C(name, age) {
    A.call(this, name);
    B.call(this, age);
}
C.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;
{   // Доп. блок чтобы не загрязнять пространство имен переменных временной переменной
    let chain = [];
    for (let base = B.prototype; base && !base.isPrototypeOf(C.prototype); base = Object.getPrototypeOf(base)) 
        chain.push(base);
    chain.reverse(); // Обход должен идти от предка к потомку, а мы прошли наоборот
    for (const base of chain)
        Object.defineProperties(C.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(base));
}

Object.defineProperty(B, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: function (obj) { 
        return B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj) || C.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
});

var pointof = new C ('alex', 35);
console.log(pointof.name)  //'alex'
console.log(pointof.age)   //35
pointof.methodA()          //"name:alex"
pointof.methodB()          //"age:35"

console.log(pointof instanceof A) //true
console.log(pointof instanceof B) //true
console.log(pointof instanceof C) //true
```

---

**Предупреждение.** Решение приведенное выше - не более чем костыль, у него нет нескольких важных свойств. К примеру, там предполагается что все прототипы объекта достижимы по цепочке прототипов - но для класса C это свойство нарушается! То есть такой класс с несколькими предками нарушает принцип композиции.

Ну и манки-патчинг `B[Symbol.hasInstance]` в таком виде - тоже не самая совместимая вещь. Второе наследование от B затрет результаты первого.

Если по какой-то причине захочется множественного наследования в реальном коде - нужно будет внимательнее отнестись к таким случаям. Например, хранить список "дополнительных" наследников для каждого класса чтобы иметь возможность дополнять проверку...

```
var s_children = Symbol("children");
B[s_children] = [B, C];
Object.defineProperty(B, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: function (obj) { 
        return this[s_children].some(c => c.prototype.IsPrototypeOf(obj));
    }
});
```

Правда, вариант выше подвержен утечкам памяти, поэтому по-хорошему проверку надо "развернуть"...

```
var s_extra_prototypes = Symbol("extra_prototypes");
C.prototype[s_extra_prototypes] = [B.prototype];
Object.defineProperty(B, Symbol.hasInstance, {
    value: function (obj) { 
        return this.prototype.IsPrototypeOf(obj) 
          || obj[s_extra_prototypes].some(c => this.prototype.IsPrototypeOf(c));
    }
});
```

И таких символов понадобится много.

---

Возможно, намного проще вместо множественного наследования использовать обертки:

```
function A (base) {
    return class A extends base {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        methodA() {
            console.log("name:" + this.name);
        }
    }
}

function B (base) {
    return class B extends base {
        constructor(age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        methodB() {
            console.log("age:" + this.age);
        }
    }
}

class C extends A(B(Object)) { }
```

Правда, instanceof для оберток работать не будет.

Comment: Очень круто, Павел! Не смотря на то, что мне кажется всё это жуткими костылищами, сам ответ класс!

Answer (score -1):

по мне так лучше выработать другой подход в написании конструкторов и определению их протоптанных свойств.

```
 /**
 * @class A
 */
function A (name) {
/*
    *   инициализация методов для конструктора типа A
*/
    SCOPE_mtd0001.call(this.constructor.prototype)

    this.name = name;   
}
/**
 *  конструктор набора методов типа _mtd0001
 */
function SCOPE_mtd0001(){
    this['methodA'] = function(){
        console.log("name:" + this.name)
    };
}
/**
 * @class B
 */
function B(age){
/*
    *   инициализация  методов для конструктора типа B
*/
    SCOPE_mtd0002.call(this.constructor.prototype)

    this.age  =  age;
}
/**
 *  конструктор набора методов типа _mtd0002
 */
function SCOPE_mtd0002(){
    this['methodB'] = function(){
        console.log("age:" + this.age)
    };
}
/**
 * @class C exstend A and B
 */
function C(_name, _age) {
/*
    *   наследование  свойств конструкторов A и B
*/
    A.call(this, _name)
    B.call(this, _age)
/*
    *   инициализация  метода для конструктора типа С
*/  
    this.constructor.prototype["message"] = function(){
        this.methodA()
        this.methodB()
    }
}
var c_obj = new C("федя", 25)
    c_obj.message()
```